# Memory leak when downloading files from Google Cloud Storage Blob (python)

Tags: python, multithreading, google-cloud-platform, memory-leaks, google-cloud-storage

I've develop a function that downloads files from a gcs bucket. It is used by threads to download compressed htmls files(<150kb) and parse them.

The problem is that after thousands of downloads the memory tends to grow linearly and this is meant to work for millions of files which will end up causing out of memory issues. Here is the function:

```
    def download_html(self, md5_hash):
        filename = f'{md5_hash}.html.gz'
        gcs_object_key = f'{self.gcs_prefix}/pages/{filename}'

        try:
            blob = self.gcs_bucket.blob(gcs_object_key)

            # same result for gz_content = blob.download_as_bytes()
            with blob.open('rb') as f:
                gz_content = f.read()

            data = gzip.decompress(gz_content)
            del gz_content
            del blob
            return data
        except:
            return None
```

the function is called in a function that simply decodes the bytes obtained from the html and repeats the process for the next file.

I've done some profiling of my program with `tracemalloc` (following this [guide](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/python/memory-profiling-in-python-with-tracemalloc/)) and found some constantly increasing memory allocations in the blob file from gcs:

```
lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py:830: size=398 B (+199 B), count=2 (+1), average=199 B
lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py:830: size=597 B (+398 B), count=3 (+2), average=199 B
lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py:830: size=796 B (+597 B), count=4 (+3), average=199 B
...
```

and it keeps on growing with each iteration and it never seems to free memory.

I've tried deleting the blob after each use and call `gc.collect()` but it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all. I also tried always downloading the same file which causes the memory to stabilize at some point and stop increasing which also makes me think there is some file caching increasing my memory?. Also tried only using a local file and no problem, so clearly it is coming from the file download process.

any suggestions on how to handle this memory issue?

#### Update

I ran some benchmarks to compare memory usage with and without threads when downloading 5000 files, and here are the results:

- Without threads:

  - Initial Memory: 112.0078125
  - Final Memory: 116.48046875
  - Memory Difference: 4.47265625
- With 10 threads:

  - Initial Memory: 130.22265625
  - Final Memory: 162.1328125
  - Memory Difference: 31.91015625

It's important to note that I'm not using a thread pool. Instead, I created a subclass of `Thread` and implemented an endless run function that fetches a Redis database for the name of the file to be downloaded. I am currently not doing anything with that file. After each download, I manually call `gc.collect()`.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions on how to resolve this memory issue.

Comment: Are you writing the content on the disk or keep the data in memory? You should share the whole code to help us to detect what is going wrong

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere for now I'm just keeping it in memory and decoding it, later I want to extract info and save it in a database. I can share the code if you want but It's nothing crazy, just threads in a loop downloading and decoding the files. I am quite sure the memory leak is in this function.

Comment: Did you clean your variables in memory? If you keep the data in memory and never purge it, it's normal that your memory grow continuously!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere manually calling `del` to delete variables and the calling `gc.collect()` made no difference. I updated the question with new results. It may be the use of threads that's causing this memory leak.

Comment: What happen if you try to close the client ?
```
client = storage.Client()
try:
    <your code>
finally:
     client.close()
```
I am experimenting a similar memory leak issue when loading pickle files from gcs

Comment: @MiguelAngelAlbaAcosta I'm downloading thousands of files, having to open and close the client each time it's a big unnecesary overhead.